# How to prevent a function from running based on host (ie web vs local)?

Tags: php, functions, server, xampp

I am using LiveReload to refresh my browser and compile my SASS. The browser extensions are not working so well for me, so I am adding the script to my footer. I'm trying to think of a way to prevent the function that adds it from running if it is on a live web server opposed to my local production environment XAMPP (in OSX 10.6.8).

This is what I have now:

```
if (! function_exists('_sf_live_reload') && ! is_admin() ) :
function _sf_live_reload() { ?>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
<?php 
}
add_action('tha_body_bottom', '_sf_live_reload');
endif;
```

Yes, I know I could just remember to manually delete it before uploading, but lets assume I forge things from time to time. Plus deleting and recreating this over and over again isn't the best solution anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$whitelist = array('127.0.0.1');

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)){
// not valid
}
```

For more info on how it works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php